# How to add two numbers in excel while keeping leading zeros?

Tags: excel

I have two cells in excel that have the following values:

A1: IND00551

A2: 10

I am adding the contents of the cells with the following formula:

```
=(Right (A1,5)+A2)
```

The answer I am getting is: IND561

Instead I want: IND00561

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TEXT():

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & TEXT(RIGHT(A1,5)+A2,"00000")
```

Comment: <Doc Brown>Great Scott!</Doc Brown> (If one can't be the first might as well upvote!)